# GCP load balancer health checks are not configured according to readiness probe

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check

In my deployment file, I created `liveness` probe and `readiness` probe in the following manner:

```
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
              path: /rest/assets/get
              port: 4000
              httpHeaders:
                - name: Authorization
                  value: Basic cnBjOnUzSGRlM0xvaWI1SGpEcTFTZGVoQktpU1NBbHE=
                - name: Accept
                  value: application/json
          initialDelaySeconds: 60 #wait this period after staring fist time
          periodSeconds: 30  # polling interval
          timeoutSeconds: 30    # wish to receive response within this time period
        readinessProbe: 
          httpGet:
              path: /rest/assets/get
              port: 4000
              httpHeaders:
                - name: Authorization 
                  value: Basic cnBjOnUzSGRlM0xvaWI1SGpEcTFTZGVoQktpU1NBbHE=
                - name: Accept
                  value: application/json
```

Both these probes work fine. 
However, I also have a GCE ingress controller and health checks corresponding to this are failing.

When I checked the health checks, I saw that it was not created the same as readiness probe. Instead I see this in the description `Default kubernetes L7 Loadbalancing health check.`

How can I change the health check so that it matches the readiness probe?

For e.g., the health checks have an option of comparing the response to the response field in the health checks.

I would expect a response of "Unauthorized Access"
So, I added it in the response field. However, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried to define the containerPort per this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584270/how-to-get-a-custom-healthcheck-path-in-a-gce-l7-balancer-serving-a-kubernetes-i)?